# Exception while executing "getSignInIntent" from another class [Google firebase auth, android studio]

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication

Good morning, formulating a class apart to facilitate the use of GoogleAPI for authentication in other projects, I sketched this idea that unfortunately returns me an error related to the support class, The error lies in getSignInIntent in the performGoogleAuth method. Also follows the key part of stacktrace. Thanks in advance for the attention!

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.getClient(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zbd.zba(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@20.2.0:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zbd.getSignInIntent(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@20.2.0:1)
    at it.myke.planel.support.auth.google.GoogleSignInSupport.performGoogleAuth(GoogleSignInSupport.java:25)
    at it.myke.planel.support.AuthSupport.googleAuth(AuthSupport.java:46)
    at it.myke.planel.activities.Login.googleAuth(Login.java:34)
```

Class:

```
public class GoogleSignInSupport {

    
    
    public void performGoogleAuth(Context context, AppCompatActivity activityClass) {
        GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = new GoogleSignInSupport().createRequest(context);
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleSignInClient.asGoogleApiClient());
        activityClass.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    
    public void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if(result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            System.out.println(acct.getDisplayName() + " has logged.");
        }
    }

    
    
    public GoogleSignInClient createRequest(Context context) {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        return GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso);
    }

    
    
    
    public void activityResultChecker(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN && data != null) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            new GoogleSignInSupport().handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
```

I’ll take any, any, any advice. It’s one of my first times doing these things, and I care about everything, even if it’s a semicolon spelled wrong in a string. Thank you again!!

Comment: Have you tried using the latest dependencies? Besides that, [here](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) is a working solution.

Comment: Changing to   Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
randomly just worked perfectly, thanks for the answer Alex!